# Azure active directory redirects to landing page always

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

So, I'm developping a react app with Azure Active Directory authentication. The react app internally uses `HashRouter`. My url looks like this

```
https://example.com/#/
```

Now when the user clicks on this link from an email he would go through the azure authentication and if authorized will be redirected to the landing page which is

```
https://example.com/#/
```

However, if the user clicks on a link that looks like `https://example.com/#/xyz` - this still redirects to `https://example.com/#/` and not to the page `xyz`. I think this is an issue with incorrect replyurls but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering. Also add the redirecting configuration you use. Good luck!

Comment: Did you do some redirect in your code? You will be redirected to the reply url which configured in Azure portal only after the authentication.

Comment: well, the issue turned out that Azure was escaping "#". So in the redirect url, I specified it as "%23" and it worked!